# Locale date string doesn't convert

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I am trying to convert a locale date string into a date targeting IE11, I am testing it in Visual Studio 2015 and `parseInt` returns `NaN`. Here is an example of my function:

https://jsfiddle.net/4tL8p5fh/

```js
function convertLocaleDateStringToDate(locale) {
  var numbers = locale.split("/");
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    results[i] = parseInt(numbers[i]);
  }
  return new Date(results[2], results[0] - 1, results[1]);
}

dates = [
  "9/30/2016",
  "10/1/2016",
  "1/1/2016",
  "12/31/2016"
];

var root = document.getElementById("root");
dates.forEach(function(ele) {
  root.innerHTML += convertLocaleDateStringToDate(ele) + "<br />"
})
```

```html
<div id="root">

</div>
```

If I run the same function in just IE11 it works fine as evidenced in jsfiddle. In IE 11 for some reason the when you input a locale date string into date it can't convert it.

Comment: Always add the radix `parseInt(numbers[i], 10)`

Comment: And note that you could do just `var results = numbers.map(Number);`

Comment: That functions works fine in my IE11...

Comment: adding the radix, didn't fix it. I just confused on why the jsfiddle works fine in IE11 but if I launch through VS 15, parseInt returns NaN

Comment: Try running that same code via VS. In other words, create an empty web project, add an HTML file with just a single `div` and a `script` element with the code above and see if it runs. Then add whatever else you have in your app gradually until it stops. Then you have your culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent in the string "9/30/2016" into the function and I was getting out ["9", "30", "2016"] which was expected but when I checked the length of "9" I got 3. It looks like there are two characters added to the string, one before and one after the number string. I filtered out those extra characters and it works now.